Counting identical subgraphs of complete graph that overlap
Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Let $H$ and $K$ be identical subgraphs of $K_n$ on $v$ vertices and $e$ edges each such that their intersection $F$ is a subgraph with $v_{\mathsf{F}}$ vertices and $e_{\mathsf{F}}$ edges. For a fixed $v_{\mathsf{F}}$ vertices and $e_{\mathsf{F}}$, how many such choices are there?

I think the case when $e_{\mathsf{F}} = 0$ is easy. However, I do not know how to do a general counting. I want an answer that is a function of $n, v, e, v_{\mathsf{F}}, e_{\mathsf{F}}$ and $\mathsf{aut}(H)$ (the number of automorphisms of $H$).

Why do you want to count this? For most applications of this that I can think of, there are easier methods than trying to derive this formula. (Not to mention that it does not solely depend on $n, v, e, v_F, e_F, \mathsf{aut}(H)$.)

An asymptotic expression of this being $\Theta(n^{2v - v_{\mathsf{F}}})$ is given on page 648 of this paper (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11424-008-9141-7.pdf). I am just trying to re-derive the expression myself. Do you have an idea of how to get it? @MishaLavrov

Finding an asymptotic expression is a very different thing from finding a formula!
